# Google web service API streets

Tags: web-services, google-maps

I am currently doing a project and I want to use some web service (if its possible from Google) that allows me to simulate what google maps does when you enter a street.

When you enter on Google maps and start typing an address there is an autocomplete with all the possible addresses for that query. The autocomplete I already know how to do it. But I need a web service from Google that gives me every possible ubication for that query.

I found this web service https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/?hl=es but I dont see any option to get all possible matches for a string.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: hey Juan.. need some help brother..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which google web service APIs are relevant for you here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker

You can find out how to call the search autocomplete feature here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

You will need an API key to call these successfully, which you get from google when you register to use the APIs.

eg.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?
```